# Continuous extension

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is there any bounded continuous map f:A to R (A is open) which can not be extended on whole R?

This is a question posed by myself.
My attempt: Let A=(1,2) then we can extend it. If A is finitely many intervals it can be extended. If A is countable many intervals then it can also be extended.

But the last claim is based on A is countable union of disjoint open interval.

Am i right or wrong?

Comment: Any function $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ can be extended by saying $f(x) = 0$ if $x \notin A$. Moreover, if you require for the extension to be continuous, then this is not always possible even if $A = (1,2)$.

Comment: @saulspatz, this function is not bounded

Comment: @BePure Oops, I missed that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(1/x)$ is continuous and bounded on $(0,1)$, but if you extend it, what is the limit at $x =0$?

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I didn't consider the oscillation.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is open and neither empty nor all of $\Bbb R$, then we can pick $a\in A$, $b\notin A$.
Wlog $a<b$. Let $s=\inf([a,b]\setminus A)$. Then $a<s\le b$ and  $s\notin A$ and we can define $f\colon A\to \Bbb R$ as $f(x)=\sin\frac1{x-s}$. There is no *continuous* extension of $f$ to $A\cup\{s\}$.